# How do you specify a debugger program in Code::Blocks in LINUX

Tags: linux, debugging, codeblocks

I was trying to debug a c++ program in Code::Blocks, but it didn't work and gave me this message: "ERROR: You need to specify a debugger program in the debugger's settings.
(For GCC compilers, it's 'gdb' (without the quotes))"
When I opened the debugger settings, I found the debugger path empty and don't know what its path.
Anyone has an idea about where can I found the debugger file.
**Note: I use Manjaro Linux**

Answer (score 0):

The Error appeared because I hadn't installed the GDB, after I install it the debugger path automatically set as "/usr/bin/gdb".